# Calculating the next proportional.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How did they come up with 24 to the following ?

> > Calculate the 4th proportional to 5,8,15 ?

Comment: 4 can't be the solution.

Comment: Sorry that was a misprint - I meant 24

Comment: $\frac{5}{8}=\frac{15}{x}$ which gives you $24$

Comment: Agree with @SaurabhHota.

Comment: @SaurabhHota Thanks ..That was simple

Answer (score 1):

$5:8 :: 15:x$  implies $5x = 15\times8$.
Then you will get the answer.